# Replace or remove toit application over USB not WIFI

Tags: toit

I have an [M5Stack Basic](https://docs.m5stack.com/en/core/basic) and installed the [deep_sleep.toit](https://github.com/toitlang/toit/blob/master/examples/deep_sleep.toit) example. It is flashed with the open source version of toit.

The application runs fine, I can see that using `jag monitor`, however I am unable to connect to it and run another application. The reason is that it is awake for such a short time that jag is unable to discover it. I have tried to reflash it, it works but the `deep_sleep` application is still there.

Can I remove the application using an USB connection, not wifi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Jaguar v0.9.1, the installed applications are correctly invalidated when you reflash, so doing:

```
jag flash
```

should get you out of this problematic scenario. Alternatively, you can also erase the flash on your ESP32 using:

```
$HOME/.cache/jaguar/esptool --chip esp32 erase_flash
```